# jQuery does not work

Tags: functions, jquery, hooks, actions, wp-enqueue-script

I am working on a project where I need jQuery for. I added this to my functions, and the scripts are loaded in my header if I watch my page source, but jQuery doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
function stn_script_enqueuer() {

    wp_register_script( 'ajax-vote', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-vote.js', array('jquery') );


    $nonce = wp_create_nonce("vote_nonce");
    $stn_vote_data = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => $nonce,
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-vote', 'stn_vote', $stn_vote_data );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-vote' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'stn_script_enqueuer' );
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't hook your function to `init` but to `wp_enqueue_scripts` (or `admin_enqueue_scripts` for the backend). What exactly do you mean by "jQuery doesn't work"? We'll need more information than this to help you.

Comment: Do I need to hook everything in that hook? Or only the wp_enqueue_script() functions. jQuery doesn't, the code in my included jQuery file does not do his job.

Comment: I would venture to guess that HamzStramGram's notion that NoConflict mode messes with a (pasted?) script is correct. Nonetheless, including (a part of) the non-functional JS would confirm said notion.

Comment: It is not a pasted script. I have searched for days for examples and in the codex to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts and stylesheets should always be loaded in the head or in the footer via the [`wp_enqueue_scripts action hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts). `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that are meant to appear on the front end

The `init` hook executes before `wp_head` which is to early for script to load in the header. The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook is executed right after `wp_head`, allowing scripts and styles to be loaded properly. This also have the benefit of naming script dependencies and ordering scripts and styles to load properly

Answer (score 2):

You should first load your scripts with a hook on `wp_enqueue_scripts` like this for example :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts' );
function load_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

What I like to do is, register my script with a hook on `init` and then enqueue them with a hook on `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
// Register Scripts
add_action('init', 'my_register_scripts');
function my_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my.js', array('jquery'));
}

//Enqueue Scripts
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript');
}
```

Then, there's something important to remember: Wordpress will load the jQuery in No Conflict mode, it means that you will have to code your jQuery dependant scripts correctly according this.

Example :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    /* if you add some code here, you will have to use "jQuery" as a selector */

    jQuery(".mydiv").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Or, you can add "`$`" as an argument to `function()` to use the default selector.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /* if you add some code here, you will have to use "$" as a selector */

    $(".mydiv").css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Hope it will help, if not, please detail more your issue.

Comment: Do you mean `wp_enqueue_script()` of `wp_enqueue_scripts()` and do I need to add the register and localize functions also in this hook, or let them outside?

Comment: * wp_enqueue_script() or wp_enqueue_scripts()

Comment: I meant hook on `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` and using the function `wp_enqueue_script()` - see codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: In your second code block, you meant to use `wp_register_script()`, I assume?

Comment: first block : register, second one enqueue. I'm sorry, really sleepy today... I edited the post.